# Error constructing Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't understand why this is giving me the error `"Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid."`

This is my query:

```
SELECT      TOP 1 pc.Comment AS [Comment], pc.[Month] AS [Month], pc.[Year] AS [Year]
    FROM        PECCS.dbo.ProjectComment pc
    WHERE       pc.ProjectId = 11501 AND
                pc.Type = 'OYEO' AND
                (DATEFROMPARTS(pc.[Year], pc.[Month], 1) <= DATEFROMPARTS(2017, 12, 1)) AND
                pc.ResourceCategoryID = 1
    ORDER BY    pc.[Year] DESC, pc.[Month] DESC
```

The parameters that I am passing are valid. What I believe is the problem is that there are records in the table where Month = 0. I believe that's causing the problem here: `(DATEFROMPARTS(pc.[Year], pc.[Month], 1)`

Comment: Looks like the issue could be in Here,(DATEFROMPARTS(pc.[Year], pc.[Month], 1) <= DATEFROMPARTS(2017, 12, 1))

Have you tried putting with '' like this 
(DATEFROMPARTS(pc.[Year], pc.[Month], '1') <= DATEFROMPARTS('2017', '12', '1'))

Comment: Are Year and Month integers?

Comment: Could it be that some records has the month 0?

Comment: @JacobH most likely not, thats why its failing, those two paramaters arent int and the last parameter is int, so it cannot compile properly

Comment: Yes they have to be valid inputs that will create a date. If some are 0 that would be invalid. `SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2017, 0, 1)` throws the "cannot construct data type" error while `SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2017, 1, 1)` will return '2017-01-01'.

Comment: They are all INT. I know that there are some records where Month = 0 (not the parameter, but the values in the column

Comment: If that is the case then you need to also filter those out of the WHERE clause or use REPLACE to turn 0 to 1 or whatever the logic is you need here.

Comment: This is why you should store dates as dates, not as separate columns for the various pieces. Doing this to a date is like storing a phone number in 3 columns or an email address in 2 columns.

Comment: @SeanLange I know already. Unfortunately, I'm supporting an applicatin I did not build

Comment: I feel your pain. What are you expecting as an answer here? You have identified what the problem is, that you have 0 for some months. What do you want to do with those rows? We can't do much except agree that having a 0 for the month is likely the issue.

Comment: @SeanLange I ended up with the answer to at least stop the query from failing. I'll need to investigate as to why there are records where Month = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by converting those months where it is 0 to a default Month value. In this case, I chose 12:

```
SELECT      TOP 1 pc.Comment AS [Comment], pc.[Month] AS [Month], pc.[Year] AS [Year]
    FROM        PECCS.dbo.ProjectComment pc
    WHERE       pc.ProjectId = 11501 AND
                pc.Type = 'OYEO' AND
                (DATEFROMPARTS(pc.Year, CASE WHEN pc.[Month] = 0  THEN 12 ELSE pc.[Month] END, 1) <= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1)) AND
                pc.ResourceCategoryID = 1
    ORDER BY    pc.[Year] DESC, pc.[Month] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [Month] an INT column in your database, or a VARCHAR with the name of the month spelled out? Using similar columns to test this, it gives me the same error, until I changed [Month] to a different column [Month of Year], which is INT. Then it works fine.

Comment: [Month] is an INT column. the problem, I believe is that there are some records in the table that have Month = 0. I think this is causing the query to crash