# SQL Server returning an error on a select that used to work

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have the following code in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(' ', CONVERT(date, fc.dataven), ' '), 
    fc.adoc, fc.nome, 
    CONCAT(CONVERT(money, fc.ecred), '  €')  
FROM
    fc, fl
WHERE
    dataven BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, YEAR(GETDATE())-1, YEAR(GETDATE())),
                                  IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, 12, MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1), 25) 
                AND DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 0, YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())),
                                  IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 0, 12, MONTH(GETDATE())), 31)
    AND adoc NOT LIKE '' 
    AND cmdesc LIKE 'v%'  
    AND evalpo = '0' 
    AND (cmdesc LIKE '%factura%' OR cmdesc LIKE '%cred%')
    AND fc.nome = fl.nome 
    AND fl.pais LIKE 1
GROUP BY
    fc.adoc, fc.dataven, fc.nome, fc.ecred
ORDER BY 
    fc.nome
```

This worked as a charm, a couple of days ago i changed a condition, from:

```
cmdesc like '%factura%'
```

To:

```
(cmdesc like '%factura%' or cmdesc like'%cred%')
```

Now, running the procedure, i get the following error:

> Msg 289, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

I am banging my head against the wall, but i can't find the error. Can someone, please, give me a help?

Comment: If you change the condition to simply cmdesc like'%cred%' do you get the error?  Does the error only occur when you apply both conditions?  From what I can see... the error lies in the DATEFROMPARTS() function.  Somewhere in there are data that is not able to be parsed as a date is my guess.

Comment: "used to work", "a couple of days ago i changed a condition"...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631439/error-constructing-date

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618 -- What marc_s said... don't set your joins in your filters.  It's just fugly.

Comment: @jarlh I changed a condition and it worked, the error is on the first line, which has nothing to do with the error, plus if i return to the original form the error keeps appearing,

Comment: We are in september.  September has only 30 days not 31.  August has 31 days, that's why it was working before.

Comment: @marc_s why did it stop to work then? Why do i have several other procedures like this and they work fine? More important, how do I fix this, with your advise? I don't really understood what I should do

Comment: @CodeNovice I think i answered your question, if you could help me with the proper ANSI syntax i would really appreciate it mate

Comment: In your second DATEFROMPARTS you specify 31 for the days. But not every month has 31 days.

Comment: I suggest a new question to parse and fix the date condition, with more explanation of what you're trying to accomplish with it and why.  Include the data type of dataven.

Comment: You should use `FROM fc INNER JOIN fl ON fc.nome = fl.nome` instead - and remove the `fc.nome = fl.nome` condition from the `WHERE` clause - this is basic SQL querying 101, really .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the 2nd `DATEFROMPARTS` because you don't have 31 days in every month:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(' ', CONVERT(date, fc.dataven), ' '), 
    fc.adoc, fc.nome, 
    CONCAT(CONVERT(money, fc.ecred), '  €')  
FROM
    fc, fl
WHERE
    dataven BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, YEAR(GETDATE())-1, YEAR(GETDATE())),
                                  IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, 12, MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1), 25) 
                AND CAST(DATEADD(day,-day(GETDATE()),DATEADD(month, 1,GETDATE())) as DATE)

    AND adoc NOT LIKE '' 
    AND cmdesc LIKE 'v%'  
    AND evalpo = '0' 
    AND (cmdesc LIKE '%factura%' OR cmdesc LIKE '%cred%')
    AND fc.nome = fl.nome 
    AND fl.pais LIKE 1
GROUP BY
    fc.adoc, fc.dataven, fc.nome, fc.ecred
ORDER BY 
    fc.nome
```

Comment: Great catch.  I didn't dig into the values being passed into the function.  Only so much time!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the OR operator like that. Try this:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(' ', CONVERT(date, fc.dataven), ' '), 
fc.adoc, fc.nome, 
CONCAT(CONVERT(money, fc.ecred), '  €')  
FROM
fc, fl
WHERE
(dataven BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, YEAR(GETDATE())-1, YEAR(GETDATE())),
                              IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, 12, MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1), 25) 
            AND DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 0, YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())),
                              IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 0, 12, MONTH(GETDATE())), 31)
AND adoc NOT LIKE '' 
AND cmdesc LIKE 'v%'  
AND evalpo = '0' 
AND cmdesc LIKE '%factura%'
AND fc.nome = fl.nome 
AND fl.pais LIKE 1)

OR //<-- here is the trick

 (dataven BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, YEAR(GETDATE())-1, YEAR(GETDATE())),
                              IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, 12, MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1), 25) 
            AND DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 0, YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())),
                              IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 0, 12, MONTH(GETDATE())), 31)
AND adoc NOT LIKE '' 
AND cmdesc LIKE 'v%'  
AND evalpo = '0' 
AND cmdesc LIKE '%cred%'
AND fc.nome = fl.nome 
AND fl.pais LIKE 1)

GROUP BY
fc.adoc, fc.dataven, fc.nome, fc.ecred
ORDER BY 
fc.nome
```

Comment: AND and OR precedence, give a look here: https://ramkedem.com/en/sql-server-and-or/

Comment: Ah, but they have parenthesis around the OR conditions which changes the order as in the last code in the page you link to.

Comment: correct, but for what I've understand on what this query have to do, you need to build 2 sub results with AND chains and merge them with OR. The error is that you can' build this 2 sets with an OR inside an AND statement chained with other ANDs

Answer (score -1):

You have missed out a space between *like* and *'%cred%'*

cmdesc like '%factura%' or cmdesc like '%cred%'